# php $_POST does not work and I get empty result

Tags: php, html, post, http-post

I searched the other posts but non of the answers worked. 
I tried to use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`, I tried to use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])` , I checked php.ini file and globals were enabled, I was using wamp server and I swiched between version 5 and 7, I removed wamp and Installed xampp but the result was the same (the result is empty page).

My code:

```
<form action="inbox.php?do=submit" method="post">
         <textarea name="sublinks" id="sublinks"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value = "senď" />
</form>

<?
if($_GET['do'] == 'submit')
{
        echo $_POST['sublinks'];
}
?>
```

**Edit:** I tried this code and it works but I need to solve the problem Why `echo $_POST` not working

```
<?
    if($_GET['do'] == 'submit')
    {
    ?>
         <?=$_POST['links'];?>
    <?
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing quote after `'submit`. Is that just a typo?

Comment: this by mistake  when I wrote the question

Comment: There's also a space between `<?` and `php`. Other than that, your code seems to work for me.

Comment: bro, I wrote the code here by my moblie, but on my pc there is no syntax error for sure

Comment: I am coding by PHP since 2010, and this the first time I face the problem

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: What's the name of the file that holds that code?

Comment: @Barmar no thing

Comment: @KarloKokkak index.php

Comment: You submit the form to the same file? To index.php?

Comment: @KarloKokkak yeah, but I tried to submit on different file and the result the same

Comment: @mhm0136466 Added answer below.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/bMB9KQY.png — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin this the first time I face the problem I don't know where the problem, the syntax is correct but not works

Comment: It won't work because you're using inbox.php in your form action, when it should be index.php?

Comment: @Karlo Kakkak I removed it, I tried to submit to `submit.php` file and not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `php` to `<?` and it works now, Thanks everyone :)

```
<?php
if($_GET['do'] == 'submit')
{
        echo $_POST['sublinks'];
}
?>
```

Comment: @Nartin S. I used the `$_GET` method to divide the page into many sections (pages) using 1 file `index.php`. e.g `index.php?page=step1`, `index.php?page=step` ..ect